# Need to capture integers for hours minutes and save it to my db as a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

EDIT: I moved the time math into the model as a callback. I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in OutstandingsController#create
undefined method `hours' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there some gem that I need to include to be able to do the time math? I thought it was included in ActiveSupport..?

```
class Outstanding < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  before_validation(:on => :create) do
    self.panic_deadline = Time.now
    self.panic_deadline = self.panic_deadline + self.deadline_hours.hours
    self.panic_deadline = self.panic_deadline + self.deadline_minutes.minutes

    self.active = true
  end
end
```

---

```
class OutstandingsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @outstanding = Outstanding.new(params[:outstanding])
    @user = current_user
    @outstanding.user_id=@user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @outstanding.save ...
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@outstanding) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= select_tag :deadline_hours, options_for_select(Array(0..99), 0)  %><%= f.label :deadline_hours %>
    <%= select_tag :deadline_mins, options_for_select(Array(1..59), 30) %><%= f.label :deadline_mins %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
panic_deadline = Time.now
panic_deadline = panic_deadline + @outstanding.deadline_hours.hours
panic_deadline = panic_deadline + @outstanding.deadline_minutes.minutes
```

Make sure that there is either a virtual attribute for deadline_hours / deadline_minutes or it's in the model schema.

```
class Outstanding < ACtiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  before_validation(:on => :create) do
    self.panic_deadline = Time.now
    self.panic_deadline = self.panic_deadline + self.deadline_hours.hours
    self.panic_deadline = self.panic_deadline + self.deadline_minutes.minutes
    self.active = true
  end

  attr_accessor           :deadline_hours, :deadline_minutes

end
```

Comment: Did it work? you might need to put an if !self.deadline_hours.blank? and if !self.deadline_minutes.blank? into the callback

Comment: so if my deadline_hours is blank, I'd get 'undefined method "hours"'?

Comment: well you could do if !self.deadline_hours.blank? else self.deadline_hours = 0 or similiar. Tbh the select is only allowing valid integers (1 or 0) to be returned so you shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform calculation on Time objects as shown in the [Ruby docs for Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-2B)

```
time = Time.now
time += (60 * 60) # Time is now 1 hour from now
```

I think my math is right :P

Comment: Sorry if this didn't help, just read the question again and realised your basically doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
@outstanding.deadline_hours.hours.since(@outstanding.deadline_mins.minutes.from_now)
```

And you should calculate this in a callback or an observer.